# Can I use the Chi squared test to see if my data fit to the Wigner-Dyson distribution indicating chaotic behaviour?

Tags: chi-squared-test, independence

I recently read the paper about Quantum Chaos in Feshbach resonance spectra of ultracold Erbium [1]. The authors analyze their data statistically using the random matrix theory framework for Gaussian-orthogonal ensembles. In the end they quantify the agreement by calculating the Chi^2 value between their data and the Poisson and Wigner-Dyson distributions.
The data consists of nearest-neighbor spacings and is expected to be Poissonian for non-interacting levels and Wigner-Dyson distributed for strongly interacting levels. The latter function is the one expected for chaotic systems.

I am now wondering whether the chi square test has any validity in this context since I read on Wikipedia that in order to use the Chi squared goodness-of fit test one has to make certain assumptions. For my understanding one of these assumptions is not fulfilled here:

"Independence – The observations are always assumed to be independent of each other. This means chi-squared cannot be used to test correlated data (like matched pairs or panel data)."

Am I missing something or could this really be a mistake of the authors?

[1] http://www.nature.com/nature/journal/v507/n7493/full/nature13137.html